# create and run saves from python program which was converted to .exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, save, exe

I have a python program that was converted to exe file for distribution. 
User can make a save. So the save file "NewSave" appears, it has some data.

By double clicking this "NewSave", it should call the main exe file and pass data into it and run it.

What is the appropriate way to do it? How to make a save (like in Photoshop, of MSOffice or whatever), so that by clicking this save the main program would be started with the data from the save.

I have no experience at coding beyond python, so i even can't imagine how it can be done. Thanks for help in advance!

To summarize: How do I pass the filepath of a double-clicked file to my python script?

Answer (score 2):

Save your persistence files with a unique file extension (.xyz), and then in your OS set the default program for opening files of that extension to your exe.

Update to OP comment:

```
import sys
filepaths = [x for x in sys.argv if x.endswith('.xyz')]
```

will give you a list of system-supplied arguments that end in your specific file extension. You should be able to reasonably expect that this will yield a list of filepath(s) from the double clicked files.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but the main difficulty is about how to pass data from save.xyz to program.exe. This is what the question was about. 
Cause now clicking save.xyz just executes main program without any data from save.xyz.